# clear a textbox with vba - getting 424 object required error

Tags: excel, vba

i am trying to clear a textbox called "text box 2"

i have tried the following:

```
TextBox2.Value = ""
```

^ gets a 424 object required error

```
TextBox2.Text = ""
```

^ gets a 424 object required error

```
Worksheets("Proposal").Textbox2.Value = ""
```

^ gets a runtime error 438, object doesnt support this property or method

```
Worksheets("Proposal").Textbox2.Text = ""
```

^ gets a runtime error 438, object doesnt support this property or method

Comment: Is this an ActiveX text box? Is it directly on your worksheet?

Comment: how can i verify i am working with an activex textbox? @Kyle

Comment: Try `Proposal.TextBox2.Text = ""`

Comment: `ActiveSheet.OLEObjects("text box 2").Object.Value = ""`?  Also, is it *called* "text box 2", or *is it* `TextBox2`?

Comment: still gives me an object required error :(

Comment: @BruceWayne yours gives me a runtime error 1004, application-defined or object-defined error

Comment: How did you add the text box? It would either be a form control or ActiveX control.

Comment: These all work for me, so it must be some other part of your code.

Comment: `ActiveSheet.TextBoxes("Text Box 2").Text` maybe?

Comment: Please post the rest of your (relevant) code.  Also, can you clarify if the text box is named "text box 2" or if you want to access `TextBox2`?  Right now, as you can see, we're just making some guesses....

Comment: if i right click on the textbox and add a macro, it defines the new sub as TextBox2_click, im assuming its name is TextBox2 - however if i click on the name box in the top left of excel it spaces out the text and calls it "Text Box 2"

it was added with form control, i inherited the spreadsheet

Comment: If you can change the object to an ActiveX Text Box then do so and use the following code: `Proposal.TextBox2.Text = ""`

Comment: solved by changing textbox to activeX textbox

Comment: So does it work now? ;)

Comment: @alilland, everything you posted originally should work now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it is a form control:

```
Worksheets("Proposal").Shapes("Text Box 2").Value = ""
```

And since you changed it to an ActiveX control:

```
Worksheets("Proposal").TextBox2.Value = "" 'This assumes that your newly created text box is still "TextBox2"
```

Answer (score 0):

Change to ActiveX and use

```
Proposal.TextBox2.Text = ""
```